# Python Django - the included URLconf '<module '{spp}.urls' from {path} does not appear to have any patterns in it

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am working through chapter 18 in Python Crash Course by Eric Matthes, which is a tutorial on how to create web apps with Django.  Currently I'm mapping a URL, writing a view, writing a template, and then trying to deploy the app on my system so I can see the homepage I created.

Here are the relevant files/code:

urls.py-learning_log

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('learning_logs.urls'))
]
```

urls.py-learning_logs

```
"""Defines URL patterns for learning_logs."""
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'learning_logs'
url_patterns = [
    # Home page
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    """The home page for Learning Log."""
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/index.html')
```

index.html

```
<p>Learning Log</p>

<p>Learning Log helps you to keep track of your learning, for any topic you're learning about.</p>
```

When I try to create the server using the `runserver` command from within the virtual environment for the project using Powershell for Windows, here's the error I get:

```
(ll_env) PS C:\Users\Samie\Desktop\python_work\learning_log> python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Samie\Desktop\python_work\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site- 
packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 590, in url_patterns
  iter(patterns)
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Samie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in 
_bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Samie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Samie\Desktop\python_work\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site- 
packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
  fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Samie\Desktop\python_work\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
  self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\Samie\Desktop\python_work\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = self._run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\Samie\Desktop\python_work\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Samie\Desktop\python_work\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\Samie\Desktop\python_work\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\Samie\Desktop\python_work\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\Samie\Desktop\python_work\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site- 
packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 408, in check
    messages.extend(check_resolver(pattern))
  File "C:\Users\Samie\Desktop\python_work\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\Samie\Desktop\python_work\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site- 
packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 407, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\Samie\Desktop\python_work\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site- 
packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Samie\Desktop\python_work\learning_log\ll_env\lib\site- 
packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 597, in url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'learning_logs.urls' from 
'C:\\Users\\Samie\\Desktop\\python_work\\learning_log\\learning_logs\\urls.py'>' does not appear to 
have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a 
circular import.
```

That's quite a lot for me to digest as a super green Python/Django user.  Can anybody see where I am going wrong here?  I know that the version of Django I have installed for this project is newer than when the book was published (2019), can that be the issue?  Thank you for any help provided!

Comment: Specify your Django version by their version code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your urls.py-learning_logs. You misspelled urlpatterns as the name of the list. The spelling should be exactly urlpatterns. Hence the error
`... does not appear to have any patterns in it ...`

Just change url_patterns to urlpatterns

## urls.py-learning_logs

```
"""Defines URL patterns for learning_logs."""
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # Home page
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Comment: Wow.  Yep, that's it.  Thank you so much!  The two hours I spent trying to figure that out are two hours of my life I'll never get back...